# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[': 'match' requires vector argument

Tags: r

I am building an R library for Bioconductor, and one of the lines in the code seems to be problematic only when calling it from another function in RStudio (i.e. when doing the lines one by one it seems to work, and when using R in terminal it also seems to work).

This is the problematic function:

```
get_cres_tiled_genome <- function(cres, assembly="hg19", chr="chr22", binsize=5e3){
  bins <- tileGenome(seqinfo(load_bs_genome(assembly))[chr], tilewidth=binsize, cut.last.tile.in.chrom=TRUE);bins <- bins[width(bins) == binsize];
  bins <- keepStandardChromosomes(bins, pruning.mode="coarse");seqlevelsStyle(bins) <- "UCSC"
  keep.bins.idx <- 1:length(bins)
  cres$bin <- Rle(floor((end(cres)-1)/binsize)+1)
  cres <- cres[cres$bin %in% keep.bins.idx]
  binned.cres <- bins[unique(cres$bin)]
  return(binned.cres)
}
```

Anyway this is the error:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :    error in evaluating the
> argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[': 'match' requires
> vector arguments
> 5. h(simpleError(msg, call))
> 4. .handleSimpleError(function (cond)  .Internal(C_tryCatchHelper(addr, 1L, cond)), "'match' requires vector
> arguments",
> base::quote(match(x, table, nomatch = 0L)))
> 3. cres$bin %in% keep.bins.idx
> 2. cres[cres$bin %in% keep.bins.idx] at generate_candidates.R#116
>
> 1. get_cres_tiled_genome(cres = cres, assembly = assembly, chr = chr,
>    binsize = binsize)

This leads me to suppose that the error is coming from `cres[cres$bin %in% keep.bins.idx]`. The question is, could there be another way to write this so that this error doesn't pop up? I don't seem to quite understand where the problem comes from, given the situation described at the start of the question.

Comment: We don't have your variables, so it is hard to guess:  but I'd suggest printing `str(cres)` and `cres$bin %in% keep.bins.idx` just before the problematic line, to see what's going on.